# USB wifi dongle install on Kali linux?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb, drivers

i recently installed Kali linux on my system and my system doesn't have a wifi adapter...so I bought a wifi dongel -Comapany and Model-
Frontech usb wifi dongle-FT0828
it says it support linux and i plugged it in it doesn't install the drivers automatically...so i went through many youtube tutorial to install the driver
and nothing worked
Could anyone of you guys help me and sort out this problem?

i have the driver file for linux but don't know what to do with it next
here is the
[Driver file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CTInyta76ut9q44ceggRJrKtLaAcTtYe?usp=sharing)

Any small help would be appreciated

Thank you!!

Comment: Kali Linux is not really user friendly, and is not intended for the average user. You might test another distro, e.g., running Ubuntu directly from a USB flash drive without need to install, to see how it handles the WiFi dongle.

Comment: https://www.kali.org/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-wireless-driver-issues/

Comment: Did you read the `readme.txt` file? Did you check in `document` directory?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yeah i did read the txt file...ended up with nothing

Comment: @DrMoishePippik i installed kali because im learning cyber security rn....is there any other way possible??

Comment: @Riot, if you're taking a class, the instructor should help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once:

`apt-get install firmware-realtek`

Reboot and if it is not working paste here the output of "lspci" command